# initializing multiple DataTable objects in one project

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

In a ASP.NET Core MVC project I use multiple views with `JQuery's DataTables` objects. Previously, all these tables were initialized with a little javascript below each View (this code was at the bottom of 10-15 views):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Now, we want to change some of the settings for the whole project, so I want to get rid of all the seperate code snippets and initialize the DataTable object from one javascript. I came up with a solution, but I want to know whether this is the best way of doing it, and if not, what the best practice consists of.

I created one small javascript file, that is loaded in my `_layout.chshtml` file, which checks if there is a html table element (auto-generated by the razor makeup in .net core mvc):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      // This snippet checks whether the html of a view contains
      // a #table element (id tag).
      if ($('#table').length) {
        $('#table').DataTable({
          "pageLength": 50 
          // other settings
        });
      }
    });
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are doing it is correct but first 
you should consider whether you need this in all you pages or not?
because adding it to your layout page it will be loaded everytime any page is requested which adds at least 100kb-1MB to your page.

second you don't need the `if($(..).length)` JQuery will do it automatically

my suggestion for such cases is to first use a class not an ID then put your JS code here in the layout page but don't load your scripts here, load them on the pages where they are used there and before initializing check if DataTable is loaded or not.

Comment: Thank you. In the project there are numerable tables (on 15 different pages). Changing (for example) the pageLength will be real tedious work.
Im not exactly sure what you mean with the latter part, about putting the scripts in the _layout.cshtml, but loading them on the relevant pages. Can you elaborate, please?